# AudioKit, dampen sound best practice

Tags: swift, timer, audiokit

I am working with a AKPluckedString(), and am wanting to "dampen" the sound over time.

I have it working ok using a callback dampening function that is called from a timer when the note is plucked.

```
@objc func dampenString(timer:Timer){
    string.amplitude = strings.amplitude*0.5
    if(string.amplitude <  0.001){
        string.stop()
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    else{

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.07 , target: self, selector: #selector(self.dampenString), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
}
```

I am wondering if Apple's Timer is the best mechanism, or whether there's a better way to do it with AudioKit. Open to any insight. Thanks!

Comment: The timer is not a good mechanism.  You could probably dive into the dsp pretty easily for this one and change parameters to give you a more dampened feel.

Comment: The dsp stuff is new to me (as evidenced by my dampening). Is there a good example to help me "dive into the dsp"? Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it should be that daunting in that it is fairly condensed into one place and you would make small adjustments and then listen to the changes.  Gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: you could also try using a sampler and set the ADSR envelope (attack decay sustain release)